# css vertical whitespace when adding link between divs

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Problem I've never run into. Searched without resolution but might not know the right search terms to use. So if already answered I beg pardon.

I had this html. (Kinda long so simplified)

```
<div class="movieabovewrap">
<div class="movieabove">
    <a href="LINK">LINK TEXT</a>
</div>
```

And I wanted the link to cover all of the movieabove div so I moved the link outside of it as in.....

```
<div class="movieabovewrap">
<a href="LINK">
    <div class="movieabove">
        LINK TEXT
    </div>
</a>
```

(it seems to be cutting off the last end div on both)
Anyways when I moved the link outside the div all the sudden I get this vertical whitespace of about 10px above and below the divs which I assume is attached somehow to the a href element. Assuming as I can't get anything to show up when I inspect the elements. Is there someway to remove this vertical whitespace with css? It kinda trashes my design. :( Any help would be mucho appreciated.

Comment: And the related CSS is?

Comment: Can you edit the post and paste the css of the classes? This is what add a CSS pattern = 'movieabove {margin: 0;}' or you have some margin in movieabovewrap and an influence on tag 'a', something like: 'movieabovewrap> a {margin: 0;}'. If this is your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Using `<span>` instead of `<div>` inside `<a>` should do the trick for you.

---

**Explanation**: The `a` tag renders a text element, if you want it's children to also act as text elements they must have `display: inline`.

`div` elements have `display: block` by default.

`span` elements have `display: inline` by default.

Comment: Razar Thank you very much for your help. This worked for me.`<span style="color:#ffffff">LINK TEXT</a></span>` But span class didn't. Forgive me for being such a nob but is there anyway to use the span class so I can change all posts via css. Otherwise when I update my css I'd have to edit every page.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` to the link, either inline or via css:

```
<div class="movieabovewrap">
  <a href="LINK" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="movieabove">
          LINK TEXT
      </div>
  </a>
</div
```

or

```
.movieabovewrap > a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```